# UIButton touch not working properly in UITableView Custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

UIButton TouchUpInside or any other event not working properly in UITableView Custom Cell. Some time touch works if i press button in corner.

Actually i want to reorder cell at any time so i enabled edit mode.

```
[_profileTblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
_profileTblView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing=YES;
```

If i disable edit mode then UIButton event working properly but i can't reorder the cell. Here i want both work together.

So, what will be the solution for this..

My Cell looks like [image: UITableView Custom Cell]

Cell's Prototype looks like [image: Cell Prototype]

Comment: Do you have a subview in your cell that the button is embedded in?

Comment: Yes.. Button, Labels, Images are subviews of UIView and that UIView is sub view of cell

Comment: You should give that UIView a background color to see if your button is fully within its bounds. Being out of its superview's bounds is a common cause of button unresponsiveness.

Comment: I added cell prototype. In that cell's background colour is blue and UIview's background colour is white. If i set edit mode to NO then its working properly.

Comment: Try this. Set the view's clipsToBounds property to YES, then run the app. Do you still see the whole button when it's in edit mode?

Comment: Yes. i can see the whole button even its in edit mode because i returning NO from 'shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath'.. If i set edit mode to NO then its working properly.. OK i will try by setting view's clipsToBounds property to YES..

Comment: No Luck .. its not cured by setting view's clipsToBounds property to YES..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42549/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-user1007302)

Answer (score 0):

At your Custom Cell End,

1) Make protocol of your custom cell's .h file like

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate
@optional
- (void)ButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender;
@end
```

2) Set delegate in your .h file and set Custom Cell's button on click method

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender;
```

3) In your .m file,

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate ButtonTappedOnCell:self];
}
```

4) Link that IBAction with Button

5) Uncheck **Use Autolayout** of your Custom Cell

At your Table View end,

1) Set Delegate of Custom Cell

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate>
```

2) In **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**, set the cell's delegate `cell.delegate=self`.

3) Implement new made Delegate's function according to your need i.e.

```
- (void)ButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender
{
//your logic
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.buttnName2 addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return Cell;
    }
//action for button
        - (void)BtnAction:(id)sender//type 1 button action
        {
        }
```